# Grab web pages from redirected URL using CURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have an url http://www.example.com/all.php?f=1. When I open the url, it redirect to http://www.example.com/all.php with value of f (where f = 1). I try to grab the redirected URL using curl but it still fails. I try to search anything in this website but almost all of the question is about how to get the url, not how to grab it.

I try with this function :

```
function get_url_content($url,$timeout) {
        $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // write the response to a variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // follow redirects if any
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        if (!$output) {
            return -1;
        }
        return $output;
}
```

But when I run it :

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/all.php?f=1';
$me = get_url_content($url);

echo $me; //it should grab the page http://www.example.com/all.php
```

It returns -1, which mean there are no output. I confused about it. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$me = file_get_content($url);
echo $me;
```

Comment: I need to get data from $_GET['f'] because it gives different output. I think the system uses session to catch the parameter and then give the redirected url.

Comment: I forget to write the single quote in $url in my post. Thanks for your correction.